# Newline Characters Causing Unexpected Behavior in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a regular expression working the way I expect it to. Based on my testing in regexhero, it seems to be related to how I'm attempting to match/capture newline characters. I'm trying to match and replace text in an X12 file; here is a sample:

```
CLP*600256417*1*50.00*28.52**WC*30567856570-0001~
NM1*QC*1*JOHN*DOE*D***MI*79999990P~
CLP*609723417*1*50.00*28.52**WC*33345470247-0001~
CAS*CO*45*21.48~
NM1*QC*1*JOHN*DOE*D***MI*738787490P~
```

What I need to do is match all lines beginning with "CLP*" that are not followed by a line beginning with "CAS*". In the process, I need to capture the two amounts in the matching "CLP" lines and hopefully capture whatever combination of newline/carriage return characters exist before the next line.

Here's the regular expression that I was expecting would accomplish this:

```
CLP(\*[^\*]*){2}\*(?<ClaimAmount>\d*\.\d{2})\*(?<ClaimPaymentAmount>\d*\.\d{2}).*?~(?<newlineFormat>[\n|\r|\f]*)?(?!CAS\*)
```

The result I'm seeing is that both "CLP" lines are being matched--I was expecting the second one to be excluded by the negative lookahead at the end of my regular expression. If I remove the `*` from my "newlineFormat" capture group as well as the `?` following it, it works as expected--only the first "CLP" line matches. I don't think this will work for me though as it will require some form of newline character to be present, but the file format I'm working with doesn't necessarily have to have any newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your **Negative Lookahead** to the following:

```
(?!\s*CAS\*)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oH0gL7/1)

Also you're not using separators inside of your character class, you're matching literals `|`, change it to:

```
[\n\r\f]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and noticing that silly mistake in the character class. I'll be sure to accept once I have a chance to confirm it works.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)